# Calcular rendimientos mensuales a partir de un marco de datos para el índice de Gini

Tags: r

Tengo que calcular el coeficiente de Gini (dispersión de la ponderación de la asignación) en 18 ETF sectoriales con datos históricos disponibles desde 2000. A continuación se presenta un extracto:

```
> head(df)
        Date  .SXQR  .SXTR  .SXNR  .SXMR  .SXAR  .SX3R  .SX6R  .SXFR  .SXOR  .SXDR
1 2000-01-03 364.94 223.93 489.04 586.38 306.56 246.81 385.36 403.82 283.78 455.39
2 2000-01-04 345.04 218.90 474.05 566.15 301.13 239.24 374.64 390.41 275.93 434.92
3 2000-01-05 338.22 215.88 464.20 542.29 298.22 239.55 373.26 383.48 272.54 430.05
4 2000-01-06 343.13 218.18 470.82 529.33 300.69 249.75 377.26 383.48 272.47 434.15
5 2000-01-07 349.46 220.10 478.87 531.65 306.50 255.17 381.19 390.23 273.76 447.02
6 2000-01-10 356.20 223.01 484.07 581.82 310.84 252.75 387.74 393.75 278.76 453.80
```

Si conoces una forma más fácil de hacerlo que mi intento, ¡me encantaría escucharla!

### El mio intento

Sé que el índice **G** es igual a [image: Ingrese la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde **E** es el promedio de todas las desviaciones en valor absoluto para todos los pares de la variable estadística estudiada:

[image: enter the description of the image here]

Y **M** es el ingreso promedio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, mientras se calcula la media de la `portfolio_monthly_returns`, **M** obtengo este error: `argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`.

De la idea de Patricio Moracho creo `portfolio_monthly_returns` with :

```
library(quantmod)
portfolio_monthly_returns=lapply(xts(df[,-1],order.by = df$Date),monthlyReturn) # What is monthlyReturn here ?
```

No entiendo este código y devuelve cosas extrañas:

[image]

```
> mean(portfolio_monthly_returns)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(portfolio_monthly_returns) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

### Data

El archivo de datos esta [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MExW-r0NNGAlMxlQh_tjOscpm6xBiMsfMKRPQykJgr8/edit?usp=sharing).

Para obtener `df`:

```
library (dplyr)
library (lubridate)
   
df <- read.xlsx ("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Sector-STOXX600", startRow = 2, colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)
df [2:19] <- data.matrix (df [2:19])
```

#### Remark

No sé porque no involve los pesos:

```
cov = cor(NewData)
# ERC algorithm
Sigma = cov
w = optimalPortfolio(Sigma = Sigma,control = list(type = 'erc', constraint = 'lo'))

w = matrix(w, 1, 18)
(Sigma %*% t(w)) * c(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

Al usar `lapply` obtienes una lista, un objeto especial en R que permite guardar cualquier información en cada posición. Puedes obtener la información con `[[ ]]`

```
portfolio_monthly_returns[[2]]
summary(portfolio_monthly_returns[[2]])
# > summary(portfolio_monthly_returns[[2]])
# Index                     monthly.returns    
# Min.   :2000-01-31 00:00:00   Min.   :-0.192013  
# 1st Qu.:2004-07-22 12:00:00   1st Qu.:-0.025159  
# Median :2009-01-14 12:00:00   Median : 0.011340  
# Mean   :2009-01-13 17:06:40   Mean   : 0.005112  
# 3rd Qu.:2013-07-06 06:00:00   3rd Qu.: 0.039820  
# Max.   :2017-12-29 00:00:00   Max.   : 0.185749
```

Para obtener información de cada elemento de la lista usa alguna función de la familia `apply`.

```
(medias <- sapply(portfolio_monthly_returns,mean, na.rm=T) )
# .SXQR         .SXTR         .SXNR         .SXMR         .SXAR         .SX3R 
# 0.0079624616  0.0051118966  0.0047279229  0.0012964127  0.0088333150  0.0082043648
```

Otra alternativa es transformar en objeto matricial

```
monthly_returns_df=do.call("cbind",portfolio_monthly_returns)
colnames(monthly_returns_df)=colnames(dData[,-1])
```

Asi los datos están en columnas y puedes obtener las informaciones

```
means=apply(monthly_returns_df, 2, mean,na.rm=T)
all.equal(medias,means)  #TRUE

covs =cov(monthly_returns_df,use = "pairwise.complete.obs")

w = optimalPortfolio(Sigma = covs,control = list(type = 'erc', constraint = 'lo'))
pie(w,labels = colnames(monthly_returns_df))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
w = matrix(w, 1, 18)
(covs %*% t(w)) * c(w)
# > (covs %*% t(w)) * c(w)
# [,1]
# .SXQR 9.238799e-05
# .SXTR 9.238799e-05
# .SXNR 9.238799e-05
```

**Editado**

Con relación a la pregunta principal. En este artículo THE MEAN-GINI EFFICIENT PORTFOLIO FRONTIER, The Journal of Financial Research, Vol. XXVIII, No. 1, Pag 59–75, 2005, indican que el índice Gini seria calculado con la fórmula:

> Gp=2 cov(rp,Fp) = 2 Sum wi cov(ri,Fp) = 2 w'K(r,Fp)

Donde K(r,Fp) es el vector de covarianzas del rendimiento de los activos con la CDF (distribución acumulada empírica) de la cartera.

Una forma de obtener eso seria:

```
GiniP= function(w,rets){
    RetSPort=apply(rets,1,function(x)sum(x*w))

    Fn <- ecdf(RetSPort)
    Fp=Fn(RetSPort)
    # xs=sort(RetSPort,)
    # rank(xs)/length(xs)
    Krp=apply(rets,2,function(x)cov(x,Fp))
    2*sum(w*Krp)
  }
  GiniP(w,monthly_returns_df)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Sin embargo sabes como calcular **E** usando lo que propones ?

Comment: No estoy seguro que esa sea la fórmula. Puedes indicar qual es la fuente de essa fórmula?  En este artículo indican otra para carteras: The Journal of Financial Research, Vol. XXVIII, No. 1, Pag 59–75, 2005 "THE MEAN-GINI EFFICIENT PORTFOLIO FRONTIER"